# Symfony3 trying to save into db with forms and twig

Tags: php, mysql, forms, twig, symfony

It is my first attempt to store product's information into mysql. I apologize in advance if the code is not in the best form, Im still learning. This is my **registration.html.twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/framework/css/myStyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}

{% block title %}Create your product {% endblock %}


{% block body %}
    <div id="container">
    <h1 id="header">Create your product and store it in the database!</h1>
    </div>

    <form method="POST" id="registrationForm">
    <input type="text" id="pName" placeholder="Product name">
        <input type="text" id="pPrice" placeholder="Product price"> <br>
        <textarea id="pDescription" placeholder="Product description"></textarea>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >

{% endblock %}
```

I also have **Product** entity class with setters&getters, not going to include it here because of amount of code.

This is my **ProductForm** :

```
class ProductForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
           ->add('pName')
           ->add('pPrice')
           ->add('pDescription')
       ;
    }
}
```

and here is part of my controller for the */insert* page:

```
public function createAction()
    {
        $product = 'AppBundle\Entity\Product';
        $form = $this->createForm(ProductForm::class, $product);

        if($form->isValid())
        {
            $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //Save into database code should go here...
        }
    }
```

For starters, it complains that it `Expected argument of type "object, array or empty", "string" given` which I guess comes from the controller where I try to pass `$product` variable with specified path to the entity class. In the documentation this part is very confusing. It says `$product = ...` leaving me without anything, I managed to understand that this is a path to entity class which should be passed to `createForm` method, but as mentioned before it complains that it is `string`, not `array`. Could someone review my code and give a feedback on what is wrong? Im really lost at the moment and not sure what to do next or how to solve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your form fields don't have `name` attributes set, which means that no data will be posted from it.
2. In the controller, `$product` should be an instance of `AppBundle\Entity\Product`, not just a class name:

   ```
   $product = new \AppBundle\Entity\Product();
   ```
3. The form will not automatically retrieve the data from HTTP request (which are not there because of point 1), you must handle the request manually:

   ```
   // inject the request here
   public function createAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)        {
       // ... 
       $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isValid()) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean by `name` attributes? I was trying to figure it out but I couldn't. I also changed the `$product` variable to the one you specified, but I still get the same error saying that it was expecting array or object and received string.

Comment: `<input type="text" id="pName" placeholder="Product name">` - the attributes in this element are: `type`, `id`, and `placeholder`. A form field, such as `input` with type `text`, needs a `name` attribute, under which the value will be sent to the server with a `POST` request. For example, a value with this field: `<input type="text" name="theFieldName">` will be later accessible in `$request` object like this: `$request->request->get('theFieldName')`, and will also be present in `$_POST['theFieldName']`.